# Reading from a byte field by void* and reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers, reinterpret-cast

I plan to read a type `T` from a byte field given by a `void*` the following way:

```
template <class T>
T read(void* ptr){
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(*ptr);
}
```

But I get some doubts: What does dereferencing a `void*` actually give into `reinterpret_cast<T>`? Just the byte at that position? Or 'magically' a byte sequence of the length of `T`? Should I first cast the `void*` into a `T*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot dereference a void pointer, it does not point to an object. But the C standard dictatetes that:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type.

We can first convert `ptr` to a `T*` and *then* dereference it:

```
template <class T>
T read(void* ptr) {
    return *static_cast<T*>(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Didn't know that with the void pointer, but makes of course perfect sense! Thanks for your answer.